# How to view Firefox functions running in a console?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm currently learning to become a proper developer for Firefox extensions. I have two questions here:

1. How to view Firefox's XML request?
2. From Firefox, how can I dump/trace every functions running in a Firefox extension?

Because I would like to know, which functions are being called, and would like to see my error messages..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829).
2. [Venkman](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Venkman_Introduction#Debugging_extensions)

Comment: I have installed and run Venkman. But somehow I don't see my Firefox extension javascript functions been traced by Venkman.
May I know why?